# How to navigate with UIApplicationShortCut and NavigationController to get to get child 4

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, nsnotificationcenter, uiapplicationshortcutitem

Case:
I have an app which holds a `TabBarcontroller`, in that `TBC` i have a `NavigationController`. I want to add `ApplicationShortcuts` in this app.
However one of them needs to be on tab 1, and 4 segue's down the line in the navigation controller. How do i achieve this?

I am able to get to the first one by using `NSNotificationCenter` and using a listener on the first layer. But this requires my app the be opened before.. Trying to send another notification fails..

My storyboard:

[image]

From variable controller -> Navigation controller -> Table View(year-- opens here) -> Table View(period-- can get here if app was opened before) -> Table View(week) -> Picker view. ( finish)

Which function should i use to achieve desired goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours i found out how to do the above.

In main class ViewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "quickActions:", name: "quickAction", object: nil)
```

Then a listener:

```
func quickActions(notification: NSNotification){
    print(notification.userInfo!)
    varDec.pressedYear = "2016" //used for the right year. (dynamical)
    varDec.pressedWeek = "13" //Used to show the right dates.
    let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("weekViewController") as! UIViewController
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
}
```

Making me eligible to navigate to any ViewController without losing my UINavigationController